# Git: Should the add/commit be run only at top level directory of a project?

Tags: git

Should the add / commit commands be run from the top level directory of the project? Or can I cd to an inner directory and run the git add and commit command from there?

For example, I made a change to a file at /src/pages/Home/styles.  Once I'm done with the changes to the file, can I run the git add and commit command from there? Or must I come back to top-level directory and then run them?

I know it is basic, silly and very fundamental question.  But just want to make it sure.

Comment: It's not mandatory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can add and commit from anywhere within your work-tree.  Just be aware of these items:

- If you're in, e.g., `src/pages` and you updated the file whose full name is `src/pages/Home/styles`, you'll need to `git add Home/styles`.
- But if you're in, e.g., `src/pages/other`, you would instead need to `git add ../Home/styles`.
- If you use `git add .` (assuming you're in `src/pages`), Git will scan all the files in `src/pages` and `git add` any that need adding, then scan all the files in `src/pages/Home` and `git add` any that need adding, and continue for all sub-folders here.

While Git doesn't *store* folders at all—it just stores files whose full names are things like `src/pages/Home/styles`<sup>1</sup>—it knows all about how your computer demands that *working* copies of files live in folders.  So `git add .` starts at the current folder and works into each sub-folder as appropriate.  But it does not go *up:* if there's a file in `src/other` that should also be `git add`-ed, the `git add .` from `src/pages` won't add it.

When Git does this "walk the tree, find file names, and add them", it will *not* add files that are (a) not already in Git and (b) listed in a `.gitignore`.  So `git add .` from the top level is an easy way to just add everything, provided you keep your `.gitignore` up to date.

You can also use `git add -u`, which updates all the files that Git already knows about; this one works from any level, not just the top level.  But it doesn't add *new* files: see the long section below.

#### Long: what to know about the index / staging-area

Note that `git add` is perhaps best described as meaning *copy a file from the work-tree to the index*.  The index, which is also called the *staging area* or (rarely these days) the *cache*, holds a copy<sup>2</sup> of *every* file that is in your *current* commit.  When you `git add` an updated file, Git overwrites the index copy with the updated file.  The copy that's in the index is in the special Git-only frozen format that Git uses (see footnote 1) and is ready for commit, so `git add` means *take the updated file, make it ready for commit, and put the updated one in the index*—which overwrites the *previous* index version, which was *also* ready for commit.

This means that the index itself is perhaps best described as *your proposed next commit*.  Using `git add` means: *update my proposed next commit.*

Use `git status` often!  When you run `git status`, you get:

- information about which branch you're on right now, e.g., `on branch master`;
- information about what's *staged for commit;*
- information about what's *not staged for commit;* and
- information about *untracked files*.

The three informational lines are the result of running *two* comparisons:

- The first comparison just compares the current (or `HEAD`) commit to what's in the index.  For all the files that are *the same*, Git says nothing at all.  The proposed next commit does not touch that file!  So there's nothing to say.  For all the files that are *different*, or are new or deleted, Git says something about that file, printing the file's name.

  The result is that `git status` tells you useful stuff about what would be committed if you ran `git commit` right now, using the proposed next commit you have in your index / staging-area.
- The second comparison compares the index to the *work-tree*.  The work-tree is where you can see and work with your files.  Remember, the committed versions are all read-only!  Not only are they in a special format that's only useful to Git, you can't *change* them either.  This makes them great as archives, and totally useless for doing *new* work.  The index versions are overwritable, but are also in the special Git-only format.  So Git has made a *third* copy, stored in your computer's regular everyday file format, for you to see and work with.

  Whatever files you have *changed* in your work-tree will not match the copy in the index, at least, not until you run `git add` to compress the edited copy down into the special Git-only format, ready for committing.  So by listing the files that are *different*—or rather, would be different after compressing down—Git can tell you what you *could* `git add` to update your proposed commit.  These are *changes not staged for commit*.

The untracked files come out of this second comparison too.  The index only has in it those files that it has in it.  (That's kind of redundant, but true.)  You can create or remove files from your work-tree using your regular ordinary computer commands, because those work-tree files *are* regular ordinary files.  So you could create a *new* file, and it would not be in Git's index.

A file that is *not* in the index, but *is* in the work-tree, is *untracked*.  That's all that "untracked" means: *in the work-tree but not in the index*.  If you `git add` this file, well, now it's in the index and therefore tracked.

To *ignore* a file that is currently untracked means to tell Git to shut up about it, and also not automatically add it with an en-masse `git add .`.  To a first approximation, that's what `.gitignore` is about: it makes Git stop whining about the file being untracked, and not auto-add it.  It has no effect on *tracked* files, which are already in the index: Git doesn't look to see if they're listed in `.gitignore`.

---

<sup>1</sup>The files stored in commits are not like regular files on your computer.  They're in a special, read-only (frozen), Git-only, compressed format, and even their *names* may not be stored the way your computer stores file names.  (This depends on how your computer stores file names—Linux's default internal file-system storage is somewhat close to Git's in many ways, but other systems are anywhere from moderately different to very different.)  This internal file format for Git is meant to be convenient and useful to *Git*.  Since comitted files are frozen, they can be shared from one commit to the next, too, which means that even though each commit has a complete snapshot of *every* file, most commits just re-use each other's frozen files.

<sup>2</sup>Technically, the index holds a *reference* to the frozen-format file's data—which Git calls a *blob object*—plus the name of the file plus a bunch of make-it-go-fast *cache* data and other things useful to Git.  For the most part, though, it works really well just to imagine the index holding a copy of the frozen-format file.